# Set the Correct Image Dimension for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I can not know how to determine the correct image dimension that will display in correct way over variety of screen, This is an example of my app home page:

[image]

I know that the screen of the devices different from model to another, and I know that I can set `Aspect="AspectFill"` to fill the entire section, But what I don't know is how can I specific an image size for each part that fit for all screen size and displayed in the correct way (ex: Assume that the image has an person and I want the person to appeare in the center of each section)?

Comment: You have to set the fix Height and Width for that image.

Comment: @Divyesh_08 That's what I'm asking about, How can I determine what is the width and height since the screen is different for each device?

Comment: You calculate it.  You can get the screen dimensions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Grid** to achieve this effect.

When defining Grid, use `*` to simulate percentage setting when setting row height and column height.

The total number of `numbers + *` indicates how many blocks you divide the row or column into. And in the definition of row or column, the `number + *` indicates how many blocks are occupied. This is the same as the percentage setting.

Here is the xaml code(Copy and paste to see the effect):

```
<Grid Margin="20, 10, 20,10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <Label BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
    <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    <Label BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    <Label BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is the problem solved？